# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código que me genera dicho error:

```
function vbAuthorMetaBox($post, $params) { 
    $fieldname = $params['args'][0]; 
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $fieldname, true); 

    wp_nonce_field('vb_question_author', 'vb_question_author_nonce'); 
    echo <<<HTML 
<div> 
    <label for="{$fieldname}">Autor:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="{$fieldname}" id="{$fieldname}" value="{$value}"/> 
</div> 
HTML; 
}
```

Y la parte que genera el error es

```
echo <<<HTML
```

---

El problema, como lo ha anotado el usuario @Aníbal Jorquera se debía a un espacio en blanco luego de echo <<

Comment: Por favor [edit] la pregunta, ya que no veo las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de PHP: `<?php` y  `?>`. Además, revisa si solo debes añadir dos signos en esta línea: `echo <<< HTML `. Revisa esta [respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20931469/4092887).

Comment: Tienes un espacio de sobra en `<<<HTML ` lo que genera el problema

Comment: He eliminado el espacio y el error sigue presentándose.

Comment: También tienes un espacio al finalizar tu string `HTML; `, La documentación de PHP dice que  `Es muy importante señalar que la línea con el identificador de cierre no debe contener ningún otro carácter, excepto un punto y coma (;). Esto, en especial, significa que el identificador no debe estar sangrado, y que no debe existir ningún espacio ni tabulación antes o después del punto y coma.` http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Gracias. Era el último espacio.

Comment: @AníbalJorquera por favor, coloca tu comentario como respuesta y así el usuario que realizó la pregunta u (OP *[original poster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253163/4092887)*) pueda [aceptar tu respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Comment: @Edns si la respuesta es correcta, por favor [acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Comment: @ Mauricio Arias Olave no he encontrado la opción para aceptar la respuesta---

Comment: @Edns la opción de aceptar respuesta se encuentra debajo de las flechas para votar positiva o negativamente una respuesta. Mira esta [imagen de ejemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0olQ3.png). Toma el [recorrido de Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender mas acerca de este, tu sitio. Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que Ocurre es que el Heredoc presenta espacios tanto al inicio `echo <<<HTML` como al final 
final de tu codigo `HTML;`. Ocasionando inconsistencias en el mismo.
La documentación de PHP indica que

> Es muy importante señalar que la línea con el identificador de cierre no debe contener ningún otro carácter, excepto un punto y coma (;). Esto, en especial, significa que el identificador no debe estar sangrado, y que no debe existir ningún espacio ni tabulación antes o después del punto y coma.

Dejo el [link](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) con la documentación de `String` donde explican la notación.